# Javascript- Two array intersecton by same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, intersection

I would appreciate if the following could be solved

**Arrays**

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
var arr2 = [0,2,1,3]; 
var arr3 = [];

arr3 = arr1 (intersection) arr2;
```

Output must be shown below

```
arr3 = [2];
```

---

Javascript button value how to add an array?

`<?php for ($i=1; $i <= 7 ; $i++) { ?> <td> <input type="button" id="myButton1" value="0" onClick="javascript:change(this);"></input> </td> <?php } ?>`

and then click the button, Clicking button of array index of value is change 0 to 1.

Comment: How is it 2  in the arr3?Please elaborate momre

Comment: arr1 and arr2 were intersection by same key,

Comment: man its not intersection otherwise arr3 s=should be 1,2,3.What algorithm u following

Comment: `arr1 intersection arr2` should return `1, 2, 3` also in your code arr1, arr2 are not arrays they are objects

Comment: You have incorrect result set in `result`. The intersection of `arr1` and `arr2` will be 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I think it is intersection by same index.

Comment: What do u mean by same index?What is algorithm?

Comment: this is array. my code is example.

Comment: Show us the code you've written by editing the question.

Comment: array of same index eg. in arr1, 1 is index 1, 2 is index 2, 3 is index 3,etc. And in arr2, 0 is index 1, 2 is index 2, 1 is index 3, etc.

Comment: my question is liked Jaccard.

Comment: please look  example for Jaccard

Comment: The Jaccard index is `|a ∩ b|/|a ∪ b|`, which doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you've described in your question.

Comment: The code shown in the question is not valid JS. Arrays are created with square brackets `[]`, not curly brackets `{}`.

Comment: |a ∩ b|/|a ∪ b| how to write javascript

Comment: @KoPhyoHtet Are you actually trying to find the Jaccard index?

Comment: @smarx Yes, I am trying

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements correctly, this should do the trick:

```
function matchingElements(arr1, arr2) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length && i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] === arr2[i]) {
      result.push(arr1[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [0, 2, 1, 2];
var arr3 = matchingElements(arr1, arr2);

console.log(arr3);

// Output:
// [ 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
            var arr2 = [0,2,3,3]; 
            var arr3 = [];
            function intersection(arr1,arr2){
                len = arr1.length < arr2.length ? arr1.length : arr2.length;
                for(var i=0 ; i<len; i++)
                    if(arr1[i]==arr2[i]){
                        arr3[0] = arr1[i];
                        break;
                    }
                if(arr3.length > 0)
                    alert("intersection is : " + arr3[0]);
                else
                    alert("No intersection");
            }
            intersection(arr1,arr2);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A short version of getting the `len = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length);`

Comment: For `intersection([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])`, I believe this will display `3`, which is very unlikely to be the expected result.

Comment: @ehsan You should probably use the *minimum* length, not the maximum. (So `<` instead of `>` in your code, or `Math.min` in @Muhammad's code.)

Comment: Based on your edit, `intersection([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])` will now display `1`, which I also believe is very unlikely to be the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on the original question, I think it's possible that @KoPhyoHtet is actually trying to compute the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of two sets. In that case, the following code should help. (It has a dependency on [lodash](https://lodash.com/).)

```
function jaccard(arr1, arr2) {
  return _.intersection(arr1, arr2).length / _.union(arr1, arr2).length;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [0, 2, 1, 3];

// intersection is [1, 2, 3] (length 3)
// union is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (length 6)
// Jaccard index should be 3/6 = 0.5

console.log(jaccard(arr1, arr2));

// Output:
// 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the shortest version

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
const arr2 = [0,2,1,3]
const arr3 = arr1.filter(item => arr2.indexOf(item) > -1)
```